# Получение имени DVD ROM'a

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!
Помогите с проблемой. На DVD диске есть программа которая запускает файлы, хранящиеся в  определенной папке. Как мне получить имя DVD ROM'а, чтобы указать программе путь запускаемого файла?

Comment: Вы абсолютно уверены в том, что это Вам надо? Почему Вы не хотите использовать относительные пути?

Comment: Все дело в том, что насколько я осведомлен, то для использования относительных путей мне необходимо включить эти файлы в проект, а их там сотни. К тому же я думал, что просто запишу на диск скомпилированную программу и папку с файлами и соответственно буду запускать файлы из нее. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Чё-то Вы как-то не так осведомлены… Возможно, возникло какое-то недопонимание, раз Вы говорите про добавление в проект… Что Вы хотите с найденными файлами сделать?

Comment: В общем у меня есть шифрованные файлы, которые расположены на DVD, программа их дешифрует в системную папку AppData на диске C. И уже оттуда запускает эти дешифрованные файлы.

Comment: Аааа, вот оно что.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
try
{
    System.IO.DriveInfo[] drives = System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    Console.WriteLine("Optical drives:");
    foreach (System.IO.DriveInfo drive in drives)
    {
        if (drive.DriveType == System.IO.DriveType.CDRom)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Drive name: {0}", drive.Name);
        }
    }
}
catch (System.IO.IOException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("IO Error");
}
catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Недостаточно прав для выполнения операции");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, лучший вариант — из `Application.ExecutablePath` достать текущий путь Вашего exe'шника и просто взять первую его часть с именем диска.